# Апроксимация полиномом, мой график не совпадает с графиками других ресурсов

Tags: javascript, математика, график

Я написал [программу](https://shumik.site/lab/09.php?full=sin), которая создает полином н-ой степени и отображает график, перебирая коэффициенты и степени чтобы вычислить f(x).

Для проверки задал точки синуса, степень полинома установил 6 (7-ю не берет, слишком большие числа) И получил достаточно красивый график который напоминает по очертаниям синусоиду (рис. 1)
[image: мой график]
Казалось бы, очевидно что программа работает корректно, но введя полученный полином в любой другой онлайн редактор я получаю совсем другой результат (Рис.2) 
[image: чужой график]
Это совсем не похоже на на график, приближенный к синусоиде. Полином правильный, проверял онлайн и у других студентов (график исключительно с интереса сделал)

Цвета выделенных точек на графике соответствуют цветам полей в таблице.

График рисует идеально, использую уже давно и проверялся на десятках других функций.
Точки нахожу вот так:

```
function func(x0){
    var y= 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < coef.length; i++) {
        y += coef[i]*Math.pow(x0, i);
    }
    return y;
}
```

поясню: беру перебираю все коэффициенты, найденные раньше, умножаю на х в степени номера итерации (от 0 к 6 в данном случае) и добавляю к y, возвращаю y в график.

Вопрос: Где парадокс, что я делаю не правильно/или возможно чего-то не понимаю.

!! Если все же я рисую не правильно !! - почему выходит очень хорошо приближенный график, и тогда почему полином, который должен построить функцию приближенную к таблично заданной не делает этого даже близко?

Спасибо всем. В математике далеко не отличник, простите если есть глупые ошибки) просто заинтересовала эта тема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сыграли роль очень маленькие числа. В полиноме, который я вывел для демонстрации было округление к 3 числам после запятой. Вставив в другие графики полные числа (вплоть до 10 после запятой) График полностью повторил тот, что получил я. Интересный опыт)

Answer (score 1):

Ваш график (кривая на черном фоне) очевидно неправильный для выражения функции, приведенного в вопросе. Парабола пятой степени (коэффициент при `х^6` - ноль) должна иметь четыре (или меньше, если у выражения производной есть совпадающие корни) экстремума. Возможно, Вы перепутали порядок степеней и коэффициентов.

Comment: А чем можно объяснить то, что вышло? Странно, что при увеличении степеней моя "функция" становиться все ближе и ближе к реальному графику

Comment: @shumik_UA Вы перепутали порядок степеней и коэффициентов.

Comment: @shumik_UA ... в выражении функции

Comment: А какой должен быть порядок? Вывел в консоль - все операции исполняются в том же порядке что и написано: 
f(3.14) = 0  + -0.045*x^0 + 4.169*x^1 + -3.323*x^2 + 0.925*x^3 + -0.116*x^4 + 0.007*x^5 + -0.000*x^6 = -0.48

Comment: Спасибо, я понял, в чем была проблема! Все в правильном порядке и последний коэффициент был -0.00014... число округлилось к 0